# Warn user of invalid email with JSF

Tags: jsf, validation

I would like to *warn* a user if his e-mail seems invalid, but still allow him to submit the e-mail if he wants to. As I've read, there's no easy way to validate an e-mail besides sending a confirmation message, but I still wants to warn him of silly mistakes as forgetting to put ".com" after gmail.

I'm using JSF, and the code looks like the following:

XHTML

```
<h:inputText id="email" 
    required="true" requiredMessage="Required field" 
    value="#{signupBean.email}">
 <f:ajax 
      event="valueChange" 
      listener="#{signupBean.validateEmail}"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="email"/>
```

SignupBean

```
public void validateEmail(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    if (email != null && !email.matches(emailRegex)){
        String id = event.getComponent().getClientId();
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Your e-mail seems invalid", "Did you miss the '@' or '.com'?");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(id, msg);
    }
}
```

As it is, the message is lost, appearing as a warning log. The `id` that appears is `j_id_f:email`, but it won't work if I hardcode as `email`. Also, I've tried using `action` instead of `listener`, but the method isn't even called!

I'd like some advice if that's the way to go, or if there's some way to do such 'weak' validation in JSF alone. I'm using pure JSF, but would consider using extensions.

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting crazy, but I'm sure I typed "Hi, all!", in the first line, and that Stack ate those first characters... *again*... because I feel that happenned before... better sleep with lights on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to update the `<h:message>` on complete of ajax request, so JSF simply didn't have any chance to present the message in the UI.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<f:ajax ... render="m_email" />
...
<h:message id="m_email" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, BalusC, it solved! I need to understand deeper how Ajax works... I'll let the answer open for one more day, in case someone wants to add something.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The basics? Just go through a sane JSF2 book/tutorial? No one would write a whole book/tutorial as an answer here.

Comment: Sorry, I was just rambling that I need to study more. But you could write a book grouping all your answers, they're a great resource in JSF common pitfalls.

Comment: Your concrete question is been answered. I don't see what else needs to be added to the answer. You just made a conceptual mistake. I don't see how it would be useful to write a book in the above answer. If you have more questions, just press `Ask Question`.